# Avoiding long switch/if for handler functions

Tags: c#, oop, state-machine

I find that quite often I end up writing code like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    HandleOtherClass(OtherClass otherClass)
    {
        switch (otherClass.State)
        {
            case OtherClassState.Unstarted:
                this.HandleUnstarted(situation);
                break;
            case OtherClassState.New:
                this.HandleNew(situation);
                break;
            case OtherClassState.Ongoing:
                this.HandleOngoing(situation);
                break;
            case OtherClassState.Stale:
                this.HandleStale(situation);
                break;
            case OtherClassState.Complete:
                this.HandleComplete(situation);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it seems like I am missing some pattern that could make this code more maintainable. I've typically read that in OO long if/switch statements should be factored out. I have considered a dictionary but that just moves the code around a little bit without really changing the architecture. How would I handle this better?

Comment: Can you show us the version of the code using a dictionary, please?

Comment: Please consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for "Best practices and design pattern usage"/etc. IMHO, that question purely opinion-based and the decision is purely aesthetic and up to you and your team rules/preferences

Comment: meh, seems fine to me... as you say, that mapping needs to exist *somewhere*, and a `switch` is pretty efficient and clean...

Comment: Aside from that, please note that this piece of code is part of a state-machine implementation. You can try looking for design patterns specialized for that. Anyways, FSM are all about detecting and reacting to type of state and type of event so.. well.. whever you will hide it via some strategies, polymorphism, if/else, or switch - that's really just pretty layer over something that **has to** boil down to a switch-depending-on-state+event, I **personally** prefer simplicity, readability, and maintainability keeping in mind that not-me will probably will have to read/fix/diagnose it later.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: I don't know OP's version, but simplistic dispatch via dictionary may look like: `var handlers = new Dictionary<OtherClassState.State, Action<Situation>>(); handlers.Add(OtherClassState.New, this.HandleNew); handlers.Add(...); (...); ` then later HandleOtherClass reduces to one-liner `this.handlers[otherClass.State](situation);`

Comment: You could refactor it to a separate function that would receive the stateful object and the handler as an interface, and then just implement that interface. I don't think that worth the fuss though

Comment: Is it clear?  Yes.  It is simple? Yes.  Is it easy to modify?  Yes.  Is it easy to debug? Yes.   Do I need to change it?  No :)

Comment: I use code like this all the time.  Basic Electrical Engineering technique for creating a state machine in software.

Comment: Dictionaries change the problem from a compile-time concern to run-time. That certainly can make the code more maintainable - but you you then need better testing and the use of `enum` works against it somewhat.

Comment: I had a solution for this kind of situation, however as it is closed, I'm posting a link of it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Znvwb5 here it is. If you have any confusion, you can ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extra complexities which has to be considered when you want to extend the cases, especially when your colleagues didn't had a course in Logic Design:

```
HandleOtherClass(OtherClass otherClass)
{
    switch (otherClass.State)
    {
        case OtherClassState.Unstarted:
            // this can become quite complicated.
            switch(yetAnotherState)
            { 
                 case 1:
                     //do stuff
                     break
                 case 2:
                     //etc
                     break;
            }
            break;
        case OtherClassState.New:
            this.HandleNew(situation);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            break;
    }
}
```

A typical way to handle this recurring design problem, is a [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). I must say, it can become quite cumbersome as well, but having it will at least lead you to the 'one' state machine instead of rewriting code everywhere, in general, we strive to readability and maintainability.

Here is an example of an typical wrapper around a state pattern, (taken from [this](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) implementation,) these are commonly used since their syntax takes away the complexity of implemented states within the classes:

```
var phoneCall = new StateMachine<State, Trigger>(State.OffHook);

phoneCall.Configure(State.OffHook)
    .Permit(Trigger.CallDialled, State.Ringing);

phoneCall.Configure(State.Ringing)
    .Permit(Trigger.CallConnected, State.Connected);

phoneCall.Configure(State.Connected)
    .OnEntry(() => StartCallTimer())
    .OnExit(() => StopCallTimer())
    .Permit(Trigger.LeftMessage, State.OffHook)
    .Permit(Trigger.PlacedOnHold, State.OnHold);

// ...

phoneCall.Fire(Trigger.CallDialled);
Assert.AreEqual(State.Ringing, phoneCall.State);
```

As you can see, there are `states` (e.g.: OffHook), and in such a state, a transition to another state is , or is not allowed, normally throug an event (e.g.: PickedUp). When such a transition occurs, an action is executed.

Comment: If you properly initialize the state machine then you modification is not needed.  The code is just a kludge for not properly initializing you code.

Comment: I don't really understand, if you mean the state machine code, it's just an example of a library which has a nice syntax. There are ton's of others. If you mean my example where you get nested switches and cases, I thought OP was heading that way and was asking for a pattern to overcome this, and yes, that can be solved with various "styles"

Comment: What I didn't like is when you said real problem comes in when you want to extend the cases".  There is no problem.  Multiple level state machines are very common.  Take a course on Logic Design.

Comment: So if you don't like what I say I have to take a course?... well spoken.

Comment: Any how, I altered the text a bit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The question as it stands is ambiguous.

If you want a State Pattern, implement Handle on derived States, such as NewState. 
Call Handle on object, which calls state.Handle()

If you want dynamic delegation to method overloads, implement Handle(State1 s), Handle(State2 s) etc. Call them by casting state to dynamic, thus: Handle((dynamic)state)